# What is causing this script to fail or fall in to a infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

Why does it seem like my page goes in to a infinite loop when the `dealHands()` function is called? What should happen is, it should call the `fetchCard()` function. That function should create a random number between 0-51, then search the `discardPile` array to make sure that the random number doesn't existed within the `discardPile` array. If it doesn't then the `fetchCard()` function should return the random number back to the `dealHands()` function so that it can be assigned/added to the `allHands` array.

```
    //Variables
    var discardPile = new Array();
    var allHands = new Array();

    //Prototypes
    Array.prototype.exists = function(search) {
       for(i=0;i<this.length;i++) 
          if (this[i] == search) return true;
       return false;
    }

    //Functions (Only the ones the that are needed for this question)
    function dealHands() {
       var cardsOfHand = new Array()
       for (x=0;x<=1;i++) {
          for (y=0;y<=1;y++) {
             cardsOfHand[y] = fetchCard();
             discardCard(cardsOfHand[y]);
          }
          allHands[x] = cardsOfHand
       }
    }

    function discardCard(card) {
    var totalCards = discardPile.length;
       if (totalCard != 0) { totalCards++ }
       discardPile[totalCards] = card;
    }

    function fetchCard() {
       var usedCard = true;
       while(usedCard == true) {
          var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*51);
          usedCard = discardPile.exists(randomCard);
       }
       return randomCard;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `i++` in your loop, not `x++`

```
       for (x=0;x<=1;i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Something so little.

Comment: That's the joy of programming :)

Answer (score 2):

`for (x=0;x<=1;**i**++)`

should be x.

Comment: Thanks so much. Something so little.

Comment: Indeed.. it's easy to go all matrix after staring at something for a long time and miss the obvious.